# How to extend common sub-generator in blueprint?

Tags: jhipster

The documentation lists common as a sub-generator that can be extended, but I can't manage to make it work.

I managed to make work the languages, server, client and others.

```
     info Using blueprint generator-jhipster-zxc for server subgenerator
This is an existing project, using the configuration from your .yo-rc.json file 
to re-generate the project...

     info Using blueprint generator-jhipster-zxc for client subgenerator
     info Using blueprint generator-jhipster-zxc for languages subgenerator
```

I tried using the generator-jhipster-blueprint to generate an example, but it doesn't generate the common sub-generator.

I copied the common folder from node-modules/generator-jhipster/generators with the goal of modifying that code. I did it before for other sub-generators, but I can't seem to make it work this time.

I am sure I am missing something, something simple, but can't find it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, forgot to do this:

```
const CommonGenerator = require('generator-jhipster/generators/common');
```

and

```
module.exports = class extends CommonGenerator {
```

The only problem is that now this logs tens of times the following line:

info Using blueprint generator-jhipster-zxc for common subgenerator